# Show that U and V are independent.

Tags: statistics, bivariate-distributions

Suppose we have (X, Y ) be a bivariate normal vector with
mean vector µ = (0, 0) and covariance matrix
$$
Σ= \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 \\1 & 2 \\\end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm given:
$$
 A^TΣA=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 \\0 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix} 
$$
With A$^T$A=I.

Let U = u$_1$X + u$_2$Y and V = v$_1$X + v$_2$Y, when A=\begin{bmatrix}u1 & v1 \\u2 & v2 \\\end{bmatrix} then show U and V are independent. First I found A=\begin{bmatrix}1/sqrt{2} & 1/sqrt{2} \\1/sqrt{2} & -1/sqrt{2} \\\end{bmatrix} then
I found that E(U)=E(V)=0, Var(U)=2, Var(V)=0 and Cov(U,V)=2 by using various axioms for  variance and expectation along with the use of my matrix Σ to give Var(X)=Var(Y)=2 and Cov(X,Y)=1.
However from here I'm not too sure where to go, I have tried by finding a joint probability mass function f$_x$$_,$$_y$(x,y) however I'm not too sure how it applies to f$_U$$_,$$_V$(u,v). Does anybody know how I go about finding U and V to be independent. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does $A$ have to do with $U$ and $V$?

Comment: The according changes have been made, thank you for pointing out that was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariance matrix of $A\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix}$ is $$\text{Cov}\left(A\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix} \right) = A \text{Cov}\left(A\begin{bmatrix}X\\Y\end{bmatrix} \right) A^\top = A\Sigma A^\top,$$
so we automatically obtain $\text{Var}(U)=3$, $\text{Var}(V)=1$, and $\text{Cov}(U,V)=0$.

---

If you want to do it by hand,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(U) = \text{Var}(u_1 X + u_2 Y) &= \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(X) + \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(Y) + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \text{Cov}(X, Y) = 3
\\
\text{Var}(V) = \text{Var}(v_1 X + v_2 Y) &= \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(X) + \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(Y) - 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}\text{Cov}(X, Y) = 1
\\
\text{Cov}(U, V)
= \text{Cov}(u_1 X + u_2 Y, v_1 X + v_2 Y)
&= \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(X) - \frac{1}{2} \text{Var}(Y) - \frac{1}{2} \text{Cov}(X, Y) + \frac{1}{2} \text{Cov}(Y, X) = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: I'm not too sure why your note is true seeing that A$^T$=A,? However thank you for the rest of the help, it was very useful.

Comment: @wizardofloz Sorry, that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @angryavain no worries, I guess it's pretty immediate that U and V are independent then as (U,V) is non-degenerate, uncorrelated multivariate normal?